# Maven: How to exclude a plugin with a custom flag

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, swagger, openapi

I have a plugin in my Spring Boot projects `pom.xml` which I would like the option of sometimes disabling when running `mvn clean install`.
Is there a configuration I could add to my `pom.xml` which would create a custom flag e.g. `exc`, which when invoked like so `mvn clean install -D exc` would build the jar, without that plugin.
For clarity, here is the plugin I would like to disable via a maven flag:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springdoc-openapi-maven.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <apiDocsUrl>http://localhost:XXXX/v3/api-docs</apiDocsUrl>
                    <outputDir>${project.basedir}/openapi</outputDir>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `<springdoc.skip>true</springdoc.skip>` to your `<properties>` section.

Then you can activate the plugin by `mvn clean install -Dspringdoc.skip=false`

Answer (score 1):

You can use profile to do that. Adding something like :

```
  <profile>
    <id>no-springdoc</id>
    <activation>
      <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build><plugins>
    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${springdoc-openapi-maven.version}</version>
    <configuration><skip>true</skip><configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins></build>
  </profile>
```

and then building with `mvn ... -P no-springdoc` should build without the plugin.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html